# WPF: how to make the Screen reader to read the text from a TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, accessibility, ui-automation, jaws-screen-reader

I have to implement the UI accessibility in my WPF application, especially the screen reader Jaws. I have a textbox where the user should enter some text. How can I make Jaws to read the text that was just inserted by the user?

Comment: Why would you use JAWS a Java API for a WPF application?  There are .NET tools for WordNet.

Comment: I know this is an old question but did you ever get your WPF application to work with a screen reader, Jaws or otherwise? I am having a similar problem with a WPF application where I cannot get the screen reader to read the contents of a textblock.